# Multiple digits MNIST and transfer learning

Tags: classification, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I have a sample of 50,000 images, some of which are shown below:

[image] $\qquad$
 [image] $\qquad$ [image] $\qquad$ [image] $\qquad$ [image]

Associated to these images are labels for the digit with the largest pixel size. My goal is to build a machine learning model to predict the largest digit in an image by pixel size.

To that end, I used transfer learning on the resnext model, but only found an accuracy of 60%.

Given that [this](https://github.com/kkweon/mnist-competition) implementation uses transfer learning to train a model to predict MNIST digits, I would now like to crop each training image to retain only the largest digit and then train the model using the [linked](https://github.com/kkweon/mnist-competition) implementation.

So, my question is, how I do crop the training images to retain only the digit in each image with the largest size.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/29180/8560, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/335107/2921, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/89470/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is cross-posted.

Answer (score 1):

As you found out, using a vanilla conv-net will not perform very well if you need to compare the scale of several objects in the image and predict the label for the largest one. To be honest, even for a human (me), it seems quite difficult to tell which of the digits is largest—that is a good baseline to estimate how difficult a task is.

There are multiple ways to perform object detection in such binary images. Actually, the most trivial one would be using graph-based approach identifying connected components (assuming pixels of digits are connected and not touching/overlapping).

In case the assumptions don't hold, you can try some of the neural network localization approaches, such as object detectors ([Faster RCNN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01497), [Single Shot multibox Detector](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02325), [YOLO](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02640)) and compare the predicted bounding boxes by size, or perhaps have a look at [Spatial transformer networks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ywv0Xi2-14Y).